# Parse textbox and convert a group to percentage of another group

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

What I am trying to do is to parse a textbox using regex into 3 groups. It is a mathematical expression and is divided into 3 groups. The expression is initially in string format but will be converted to integer to perform calculation and then converted back to string. Group 1 contains integer. Group 2 
contains the operand and group 3 contains integer.

It is a calculator app so upon button click(percent button) I want to convert Group 3 to a percentage of Group 1.

This is what I have tried but it is not working. What am I missing?

The expression in the textbox looks like:

```
2 + 3 
2 * 3 
2 / 3 
2 - 3
```

And I want to convert the "3" in each expression to 3% of 2.
Then display the change:

```
2 + 0.06 
2 * 0.06 
2 / 0.06 
2 - 0.06
```

```
String Expression = richTextBox1.Text;
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"([\+-]?\d+\.*\d*[eE][\+-]?\d+|[\-\+]?\d+\.*\d*)([\/\*\+\-])(-?\d+\.*\d*[eE][\+-]?\d+|-?\d+\.*\d*)");

Match m = regEx.Match(Expression);

while (m.Success)
{
    double result = Convert.ToDouble(m.Groups[3].Value);
    result = Convert.ToDouble(m.Groups[1].Value) / 100;
    if ((result < 0) || (m.Index == 0)) 
        Expression = regEx.Replace(Expression, result.ToString(), 1);
    else 
        Expression = regEx.Replace(Expression, "+" + result, 1);
    m = regEx.Match(Expression);
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the text you're trying to parse?

Comment: What part is not working? You haven't used group 2 or 3 in your calculation, you are only using the group 1 in your calculation. Why not just ask the user to enter the group 1 input?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but the your regex won't correctly match int's/floats. This might be better (without whitespace) `@"^([+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)([/*+-])([+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)$"`

Comment: The expression in the textboxt looks like:

2 + 3 or 2 * 3 or 2 / 3 or 2 - 3

And I want to convert the "3" in each expression to 3% of 2. Then display the change:

2 + 0.06 or 2 * 0.06 or 2 / 0.06 or 2 - 0.06

Comment: I would never dare to write my own formula parser. Despite that if I would, I would not use Regex. Instead [I would (and did) use a finished one](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Okay using the NCalc package how would I write a formula to evaluate the the textbox and perform the desired "group 3" conversion w/o displayiing the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think writing a formula parser is not in scope of this question. I can just show where problems with current approach are.

First, you did not account for whitespace between the values.
Second, you replaced the whole expression with just a part of it.
Third, you use several assignments for result, but we are only interested in Group 3.

Here is "fixed" code: the replacement callback method...

```
public static string Repl(Match m)
{
    double result = Convert.ToDouble(m.Groups[3].Value);
    result = Convert.ToDouble(m.Groups[3].Value) / 100 * 2;
    if (result < 0 || m.Index == 0)
       return m.Value.Replace(m.Groups[3].Value, result.ToString());
    else 
       return m.Value.Replace(m.Groups[3].Value, "+" + result.ToString());
}
```

and this is how we are calling it:

```
String Expression = "2 * 3";
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"([+-]?\d+\.*\d*[eE][+-]?\d+|[-+]?\d+\.*\d*)\s*([/*+-])\s*(-?\d+\.*\d*[eE][+-]?\d+|-?\d+\.*\d*)");
Expression = regEx.Replace(Expression,Repl);
Console.WriteLine(Expression);
```

Surely you can convert this callback method to a lambda expression.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/TyCPvu)

Answer (score 0):

The scope of this question doesn't seem too difficult, if you're just converting the second number in the expression.  I would use `Regex.Split()` with a pattern of :

```
"([-+/*])"
```

This will split the expression into three pieces:

- First number
- Operator
- Second number

Then just convert the second number to be 3% of 2 and `String.Join()` the pieces back together.

Code Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> expressions = new List<string>
        {
            "2 + 3", 
            "2 * 3", 
            "2 / 3", 
            "2 - 3" 
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Before: ");
        expressions.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < expressions.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] pieces = Regex.Split(expressions[i], "([-+/*])")
                .Select((p, j) => j == 2 ? (2 * 0.03).ToString() : p.Trim())
                .ToArray();
            expressions[i] = String.Join(" ", pieces);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("After: ");
        expressions.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Before: 
2 + 3
2 * 3
2 / 3
2 - 3

After: 
2 + 0.06
2 * 0.06
2 / 0.06
2 - 0.06
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ShY066)